# Does the reverse saturation current aka “Is” in the Ebers-Moll equation have any link to Iceo or Icbo

Tags: bjt

I can understand what are the leakage currents Icbo and Iceo but I don’t know and cannot find whether one of them is the same thing with the reverse saturation current in Ebers Moll equation namely Is.

Is there any relation between the  reverse saturation current **Is** and “Icbo or Iceo”?